# How to fix an error where the POST method is not supported using Laravel [solved]

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to have a post messaging feature on my Laravel website I am creating.

My controller which specifically on index function

```php
public function index()
    {
        $messages = DB::table('messages')->where('user_id', 1)->get();
        // dd($messages)
        return view('home', [
            'messages' => $messages
        ]);
    }
```

My blade, home.blade.php

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Recent updates</div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <form action="{{ route('home') }}" method="post">
            <textarea name="body" id="body "rows="3" class="form-control" placeholder="What's in your mind"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" name="post" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="card-body">
        @foreach($messages as $message)
            {{ $message->body }}
            <br />
            <small>{{ $message->create_at }}</small>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

My routes, on web.php

```php
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Is there a way I can pass the message from blade to index function.
Note: this was solved years ago by halfer on Oct 1, 2023, and this is content was edited this January 2, 2024.

To explain solutions.

The new file structure would be:

```
app
|_ Http
 |_ Controllers
   |_ TaskController.php
 |_ Models
   |_ Task.php
...
|_resources
 |_ view
  |_ layouts
    |_ apps.blade.php 
  |_ post
    |_ home.blade.php
    |_ edit-form.blade.php
    |_ update.blade.php
route
 | web.php
```

My new blade will be:

Inside the view/post directory
On my new home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Posts')
@section('content')

<div class="card-body">
  @foreach($posts $post )
    <a href="{{ route('post.edit', ['post_id', $post->id]) }}">
      {{ $post->title }} - {{ $post->description }} 
    </a>
    <small>{{ $post->create_at }}</small>
  @endforeach
 </div>

@endsection
```

On my new edit-form.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Edit Post')
@section('content')

  <div class='card'>
    <div class='card-header'>Recent updates</div>

    <div class='card-body'>
        <form action="{{ route('post.update') }}" method='post'>
        @csrf  
            <textarea name='body' id='body' rows='3' class='form-control' placeholder='What is in your mind'></textarea>
            <button type='submit' name='post' class='btn btn-primary'>Post</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>

@endsection
```

And my new controller is as PostController from HomeController:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('home', ['posts' => $posts]);
}

public function edit(string $post_id)
{
    $post = Post::where('post_id', '=', $post_id)->first();   

    returnn view('post.edit-form', [
       'post ' => $post 
    ]);
}

// I used massive assignment for Post Request
public function update(PostRequest $request, string $post_id)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();
    $update_post = Post::update($validated);

    return view('post.index', ['posts' => $posts])
      ->('success', 'Post has been updated');
}
```

Here is my new route at web.php

```
<?php

// By default define the Route class
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

// I defined the PostController controller
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

// I defined the routes for edit and update
// The edit is responsible to display the form
// The update is responsible to update the requested data
Route::get('post/edit/{post_id}', [PostController::class, 'edit'])->name('post.edit');
Route::put('post/update/{post_id}', [PostController::class, 'update'])->name('post.update');
```

Note: If you noticed a syntactical error on my script, correction is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple you should see some tutorials and read [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests) and here is a basic example of post request.

```
public function post_request(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
      'body' => 'required|string'
    ]);

   Model::create($request->only('body'));

   return redirect()->back();
}
```

web.php:

```
Route::post('sample/post','Mycontroller@post_request')->name('post.test')
```

view.blade:

```
 <form action="{{ route('post.test') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
   <textarea name="body" id="body "rows="3" class="form-control" placeholder="What's in your mind"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" name="post" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, this is correct. this is already solved. I cannot recall since it was a long time ago. Thank you Salman.

Answer (score 2):

Your `home` route is registered for GET requests only (`Route::get`), you need to define a route for your POST request too. You can do this like so:

```
Route::post('/home', 'HomeController@create')->name('status-update');
```

Then you would also need to change your form action to the new route

```
<form action="{{ route('status-update') }}" method="post">
```

Refer to the routing chapter of Laravels excellent documentation for further details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing

Comment: Sorry  for late response. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a post route like that :

```
Route::post('/home','HomeController@homeFunction');
```

And don't forget put the `@csrf` in html form

Comment: Thanks for additional info.

Answer (score 1):

//view

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Recent updates</div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <form action="{{ route('home') }}" method="post">
             {{ csrf_field() }}
            <textarea name="body" id="body "rows="3" class="form-control" placeholder="What's in your mind" required></textarea>
            <button type="submit" name="post" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="card-body">
        @foreach($messages as $message)
            {{ $message->body }}
            <br />
            <small>{{ $message->create_at }}</small>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

//controller

```
public function post_record(Request $request)
{
     $this->validate($request, [

          'body'      => 'required|string',
          ]);

     $message=$request->input('body');

     DB::table('table')->insert(['msgfield'=>$message]);
}
```

//route

```
Route::post('/home','YourController@post_record')->name('home');
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. Thanks for helping. This was resolved by Salman.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was answered by Salman Zafar

In controller

```
public function post_request(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
      'body' => 'required|string'
    ]);

   Model::create($request->only('body'));

   return redirect()->back();
}
```

In route

```
Route::post('sample/post','Mycontroller@post_request')->name('post.test');
```

In view

```
 <form action="{{ route('post.test') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
   <textarea name="body" id="body "rows="3" class="form-control" placeholder="What's in your mind"></textarea>
   <button type="submit" name="post" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
```